# Converting TimeSpan Hours to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-3.5, converters, timespan

Commented Code As Posted by Arif Eqbal the below Converts a TimeSpan to a DateTime

A problem with the above is that the conversion returns the incorrect number of days as specified in the TimeSpan. Using the above, the below returns 3 and not 2 as specified. The minutes and seconds are preserved. ~~ Ideas on how to preserve the 2 days in the TimeSpan arguments and return them as the DateTime day?

A second problem of this conversion is that if I want to add the hours in days to the hours in the TimeSpan and return them as DateTime hours, e.g. Format = "hh:mm" or 49:30, there is no way to add the hours together in a DateTime object. Essentially I want to convert TimeSpan.TotalHours to the Hours component of the DateTime object. I understand this likely requires a string conversion, but there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution in .Net 3.5. Unfortunately I do not have the luxury of the converters from 4.0 or 4.5.

```
 public void test()
    {
     // Arif Eqbal
     //DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01);
     //TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
     //dt = dt + ts;

    _ts = new TimeSpan(2, 1, 30, 10);`    
    var format = "dd";    
    var returnedVal = _ts.ToString(format);    
    Assert.That(returnedVal, Is.EqualTo("2")); //returns 3 not 2
    }
```

Thanks - Glenn

Comment: Shouldn't the `"dd"` format give the string `"02"`? If you don't want zero padding, use format `"%d"`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, it does. I posted an answer at the same time!

Comment: Not sure I understand the last part of the question, but the `operator +` has an overload you can use like this: `var resultDateTime = yourDateTime + yourTimeSpan;`

Comment: Thanks Jeppe - I've used var resultDateTime = yourDateTime + yourTimeSpan in the date conversion (which is resulting in a 3 rather than 2 for the days component. What I want to do in part 2 is return the hh portion of the DateTime as 49:30 for the format "hh:mm". With the above, 1 is returned. Thanks - Glenn

Answer (score 1):

It returns "02" when I try it.

The "dd" format makes it put leading zeroes if necessary, but you have failed to account for this in your `Is.EqualTo("2")`

Therefore your assertion fails (but you mistakenly thought that it was returning 3).

---

I tested this by copy/pasting your code into a Console app:

```
var _ts = new TimeSpan(2, 1, 30, 10);    
var format = "dd";    
var returnedVal = _ts.ToString(format);   
Console.WriteLine(returnedVal); // Prints "02"
```

---

[EDIT] Aha! Now I know what you've done. Your code is actually like this:

```
var _ts = new TimeSpan(2, 1, 30, 10);    
var format = "dd";    

DateTime formatDateTime = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01);
var conversionResult = formatDateTime + _ts;
string result = conversionResult.ToString(format);
```

But note what the type of `conversionResult` is `DateTime`, *not* `TimeSpan`.

So you're doing here is using the format "dd" with a `DateTime` object, and `"dd"` for a DateTime means "The day of the month".

So you took the date 2012-01-01 and added 2 days (and a bit) to it to make it 2012-01-03, and then you made a string out of the day of the month part, which of course is `3`.

Problem explained!

Comment: Thanks - I tried both "dd", "%d", "dd" they work as defined but I still get a 3 back when passing TimeSpan(2, 1, 30, 10). Let me know if you see any anomalies with the below. Thanks - Glenn DateTime formatDateTime = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01);
    
var conversionResult = formatDateTime + timeSpan; 

string result = conversionResult.ToString(format);

Comment: Matthew - If you would be willing to share the snippet that returned you 2, that would be great. Thanks - Glenn

Comment: @user2284452 Sure, I'll add it to my answer. Note that it returns "02" no "2"

Comment: Thanks Matthew - Ok, that likely explains it. I'm guessing you are using 4.0 or 4.5 as 3.5 does not have a formatting arg for .ToString() on the TimeSpan object. I created my own extension method to do so. I was following the above conversion to DateTime and then retrieving "dd" off the DateTime object. Sorry if that was confusing. Glenn

Comment: Matthew - Just saw your note - correct as above. Any thoughts on how to preserve the 2 when converting the TimeSpan to the DateTime object? Thanks - Glenn

Comment: @user2284452 You can't preserve it, its value is lost. It's like adding 5 to 3 to get 8 and then wondering how to preserve the 3. You have to keep the TimeSpan around to preserve it. You could write a wrapper class the keep both the DateTime and TimeSpan together, but you can't avoid keeping both their values if you need both their values.

Comment: (What I mean is, you will need to keep `_ts` around if you need to use its `Days` component.)

Comment: Thanks Matthew - More fun ahead. Glenn